# Problem with rendering text objects in nvim on Linux Mint 21.2 MATE 64-bit

Tags: linux, neovim, linux-mint, vim-plugin

I've installed neovim v.0.10 and the latest NvChad on Linux Mint 21.2 MATE 64-bit:

```
$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.10.0-dev
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Run "nvim -V1 -v" for more info
```

and have the following problem (look at the symbol on the left side of each text object) with rendering text:
[image]

What I can do to fix this problem? Maybe I need to install some additional packages with fonts?

NvChad successfully installed all packages, I have tried to select different themes, but have the same problem.

Comment: You are missing a font. Not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your terminal missing some fonts and icons, i was researched this answer and font doesn't provide your icons.

Find NerdFonts patched version of your favourite font, install and set your terminal. I will give the link :
https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have found the good instruction for install these fonts https://gist.github.com/matthewjberger/7dd7e079f282f8138a9dc3b045ebefa0